# Angular 5 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined when am trying to subscribe which is not a type of Service Method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a method like,

```
validatingUpdateBtn: boolean;

Validating(): Observable<boolean> {

    //Do some function

    if (this.validatingUpdateBtn) {
         return Observable.of(true).map(res => res);
    }
    else {
         return Observable.of(false).map(res => res);
    }
}
```

Now as show in the below method, am subscribing to above method.

```
handleSelection(){
    this.Validating().subscribe(
          (res) => {
            if (res) {
              //Do some work
            }else{
              //Do some work
            }
          }
        )
}
```

but am getting **Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined** when am trying to subscribe **Validating()** method.

Am not getting whats going wrong?

Comment: can you show how `handleSelection()` method is being called? And do you have any `return`s before in the function `Validating()`?

Comment: @AmirArbabian handleSelection() is directly called in ngOnInit()

Comment: and what about the second question?

Comment: No i don't have any!

Comment: Can you add `console.log(this.Validating())` into beginning of the `handleSelection()` and verify whether it's really undefined

Comment: @AmirArbabian Thats the problem I think! Am getting undefined when i do console.log(this.Validating())

Comment: Can you post the whole `Validating()` method code?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Its too big to post!

Comment: So maybe the problem is that your posted `if` block with observables already inside of something else like `switch`... `case` or another `if`? If it's too big, maybe you can upload it somewhere and post just link here, because it would allow me to say for sure where is the problem?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Exactly! It was inside switch() statement. Now I moved it outside switch statement and its working! Thanks bro and up-voted for your above comment!

Comment: Glad that it helped, should i create an answer so the question will be marked as closed?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Sure!

Comment: done, hope that would help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out with **@Chandan Y S**, the problem was that current `if` statement was inside of another conditional structure, in this case `switch` statement, and in some particular scenario execution didn't even come to that `if-else` statement which was returning observables, and that is why function didn't return anything.

Comment: That was my problem!

Comment: @Chandan Y S If this answer worked for you mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

validatingUpdateBtn: boolean;

```
ValidatingFunction = () => {

    //Do some function

    if (this.validatingUpdateBtn) {
         return Observable.of(true).map(res => res);
    }
    else {
         return Observable.of(false).map(res => res);
    }
}

Validating = ValidatingFunction.asObservable();
```

Try this maybe it's work

Comment: Unfortunately arrow function doesn't have `asObservable()` method as well, only `Subject` has

Answer (score 0):

**You have nothing to `map` therefore remove `map` operator after `of`. Use `of` operator from `rxjs/observable/of` as below.**

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

  Validating(): Observable<any> {

    let res = this.validatingUpdateBtn ?  of(true) : of(false);
    return res;
  }

handleSelection(): void{

  this.Validating().subscribe( res => {
    if (res) {
      console.log(res);
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vc8ghk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)